# Count the number of punctuation symbols in a string Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a question how can I count the number of punctuation symbols in a string.

**Here is my code snippet**

```
fun punctuationCount(stringValue: Editable): Int {
        val trimmedStr = stringValue.trim()
        return if (trimmedStr.isEmpty()) {
            0
        } else {
           return trimmedStr.split("[a-zA-Z&&[ \t]]".toRegex()).size
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could iterate through the string and increment a counter if there is a match.

Comment: I have done it, but I thought maybe there is an advanced solution how to count punctuation char

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version of your function that demonstrates what you're asking for:

```
fun punctuationCount(stringValue: String): Long {
    val trimmedStr = stringValue.trim()
    return if (trimmedStr.isEmpty()) {
        return 0
    } else {
        val exp = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}")
        val matcher = exp.matcher(trimmedStr)
        return matcher.results().count()
    }
}
```

If you don't like the Pattern library's definition of what constitutes punctuation, you can replace the line that computes the Pattern object with something like this that lets you define punctuation characters explicitly:

```
val exp = Pattern.compile("[!@#\$%.]")
```

Comment: I have a question why do i get in return "matcher.results().count()" that results() are unresolved reference?

Comment: That's strange.  I can't think of why.  Does this happen for all input strings?  If you can paste the actual error message here, that might help.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the built-in `count` function on `CharSequence` to count the occurrence of arbitrary characters.

```kotlin
val testString = "Some string containing punctuation, like !, @, #, etc."
val punctuationChars = setOf('!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '.')

val occurrences = testString.count { char -> char in punctuationChars }

println("I've counted $occurrences occurrences!")
```

If you need this functionality more often, you might want to extract it into an extension function, e.g.

```kotlin
fun CharSequence.countCharacters(searchedCharacters: Set<Char>): Int =
    this.count { char -> char in searchedCharacters }

val punctuationChars = setOf('!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '.')

fun CharSequence.countPunctuationCharacters(): Int =
    this.countCharacters(punctuationChars)
```

Then you can do

```kotlin
val occurrences = testString.countPunctuationCharacters()
```

---

Thanks to @CryptoFool for the example string.

Answer (score 1):

Another variation - the Unicode standard [defines a bunch of categories (see 4.4)](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/ch04.pdf) that a character can fall into, and [those are present in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-char-category/), so you could make use of those if you like

```
import kotlin.text.CharCategory.*

val punctuation = setOf(
    DASH_PUNCTUATION, START_PUNCTUATION, END_PUNCTUATION,
    CONNECTOR_PUNCTUATION, OTHER_PUNCTUATION
)

val testString = "Some string containing punctuation, like !, @, #, etc."

fun main() {
    testString.count { it.category in punctuation }.run(::println)
}

>>> 8
```

You'd have to decide if those cover your needs, or which ones to include and exclude (and *symbols* are a different category class). Just throwing it out there as an option / something to know about!